# Bot framework skill errors out on teams - valid domains correct

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a virtual assistant. I am trying to add the todo skill (with no changes) to this virtual assistant. The skill works via the bot in web chat and emulator, but it does not work in teams. In teams the bot with present me with the oAuth prompt. After logging in the window closes and the bot returns a 'Sorry, something went wrong' message. Application Insights tells me there's a 403 error when reaching out to smba.trafficmanager.net.

I've been reading up on the error, and it usually seems to have something to do with the 'validDomains' section of the manifest. My manifest includes the bot, the skill, and "token.botframework.com." I do not have direct access to upload this file, so I need to be relatively sure whatever changes I make will address the issue.

I've also seen mention that the app registration needs to be for all microsoft account types, which I have configured for both my bot and the skill.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please [setup your bot locally using ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#tunnel-using-ngrok) and check which step you are getting this error? Also, do you have more details from App Insights like which request/response?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Wajeed-MSFT - we're getting a 404 when the skill reaches out to api.botframework.com/api/usertoken/gettoken. 

I'm not sure how I'll get ngrok to work, pushing a change to the teams' manifest is a bit of a process at my company.

Comment: Does your bot inherit from TeamsActivityHandler and handle OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync as demonstrated here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/Bots/TeamsBot.cs#L34

Comment: I don't think it does. I will verify that shortly. Do both the bot and the skill need that implementation? I've managed to confuse myself with the authentication model pretty well - I'm going to assume I know nothing until I get something working.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I did have the : TeamsActivityHandler on my activity handler, and it does implement the OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync method. I'm afraid I don't know what else to check on. Any ideas @Wajeed-MSFT?

Comment: Getting it working on Local using ngrok would be the fastest way to check and debug it. Meanwhile, let me also set it up and check.

Comment: I've requested the ability to update the manifest file myself. Thank you for taking the time to check on your side.

Comment: Despite no changes on my end, this is working again. I'm trying to get clarification from our infrastructure teams on what might have changed on their end that could have caused a problem.